# mpi4py with processes and threads

Tags: python, multithreading, mpi

Hi This is a pretty specific question, so I hope StackOverflow is meant for all programming languages and not just javascript/html

I am writing a multi program in MPICH2 (popular message passing interface). My program is written in Python so I use the MPI4Py Python bindings. MPI is best for situations with no shared memory, therefore, it is not ideal for multicore programming. To use the full 4 cores of my 5 node cluster I am further using threads. However, I have noticed that using threads actually slows my simulation down. My program is several tens of thousands of lines of code, so I can not put it all up, but here is the snippet which is causing problems

```
from threading import Thread
...
threadIndeces=[[0,10],[11,20],[21,30],[31,40]] #subset for each thread
for indeces in treadIndeces:
  t=Thread(target=foo,args=(indeces,))
  t.start()
```

Also, I make sure to join the threads later. If I run it with no threads, and just call `foo` with all the indeces, it is about 10-15x times faster. When I record the times of the multithreaded version, the creation of the threads in the call `t=Thread(target=foo,args=(indeces,))` takes around 0.05 seconds, the join similarly takes 0.05 seconds but the `t.start()` calls takes a whopping 0.2 seconds.

Is `start()` an expensive call? Should I be changing my approach? I thought about keeping a pool of threads rather than creating new ones every iteration, but it does not seem like the 
`t=Thread(target=foo,args=(indeces,))` is what's causing the slow down.

Also, incase anyone wants to know the complexity of the `foo`, here is one of the functions which gets called `i` times for the `indeces` every iteration (non discrete time):

```
def HD_training_firing_rate(HD_cell):
    """During training, the firing rate is governed by the difference between the 
       current heading direction and the preferred heading direction. This is made
       to resemble a Gaussian distribution
    """
    global fabs
    global exp
    global direction

    #loop over twice due to concurrent CW and CCW HD training
    for c in [0,1]:
        d=direction[c]
        dp=HD_cell.dp  #directional preferance
        s_d=20.0  #standard deviation
        s_i=min(fabs(dp-d),360-fabs(dp-d)) #circular deviation from preferred dir.

        HD_cell.r[c]=exp(-s_i*s_i/(2*s_d*s_d))  #normal distribution
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need threads, python may not be your best option due to the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) which prevents true concurrency.  See also [Dave Beazly's disturbing talk](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf).

You might be better off just running 20 processes to keep your 4 cores and 5 nodes busy, and just use MPI for all communication.

Python incurs a lot of overhead on the big iron--you may want to think about C or C++ (or dare I say Fortran?) if you're really committed to a joint threads/message passing approach.

Comment: +1 - I'm not sure what the advantage of threads here is.  It looks like each thread is doing something completely independant?   If so, what's the advantage of using threads over MPI?       In terms of finding the performance issues, you'll be better off taking the larger-scale decomposition out of the equation and just focussing on getting things to run on one shared-memory box as fast as possible, _then_ reintroduce the cross-node MPI stuff.   If you're stuck doing the whole thing in python, you may well end up finding that process-based approaches like multiprocessing outperform threads.

Comment: @Drew Hall: I initially used C, but that language is very tedious, Python is easier to use.

Comment: @Drew Hall, Jonathan Dursi: People seem to forget that MPI assumes no shared memory, whereas threads allow for shared memory. The issue here is global variables. I do a lot of scaling which requires calculating the global maximum. With threads this can easily be achieved, in fact it's trivial. If I use MPI and run more than one processes on a single node then they will have to communicate these global maximas. Communication is, forgive my language, a pain in the ass.

Comment: @puk:  Even with multiple processes, you should be able to open a shared memory segment for processes on the same node.  I don't know how to do that in python but I'd be surprised if it can't be done.

Comment: @Drew Hall: I just wanted to point out why I chose to use threads in addition to MPI. I am not 100% sure, but I am 99% sure that one can not have shared memory via MPI.

Comment: @puk sure, MPI doesn't expose shared memory (although it takes advantage of it where available), but mpi_allreduce() trivially lets you find global maxima (for instance).

Comment: @Drew: I gave up on functions like `reduce` and `gather` when I was using MPI with C. I noticed that it was introducing a linear decrease in performance. I traced my program for weeks and eventually found this function to be the cause. However, I don't think I'd use the word 'trivial' here, for example what if your program is smaller than the number of nodes (ie. simulating 100 neurons on 200 computers), then you 'could' cause an error when you try to reduce from ranks which are null. This can easily be programmed around, but nothing beats that shared memory ;-)